# Holonomy twisting

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, definition, topological-field-theory

There is [Witten's topological twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_string_theory#The_topological_twist) of standard SUSY QFTs with enough SUSY into [Witten-type TQFTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory#Witten-type_TQFTs). What is a holonomy twist?

Comment: "I will call this a _holonomy twist_." See p. 10 of [this pdf](https://www.math.umass.edu/~mirkovic/0.SEMINARS/2.GeometricLanglands/3.KW/9.pdf).

Comment: So what? Kevin Costello: Supersymmetric gauge theory and derived geometry: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDV0MdA2YBM , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trMrhmde-qM and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgPBZ-Awo1I

Comment: @lav, if you would like to merge your accounts, please see [this page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).